# How many European cup finals have been played in the stadium of one of the finalists?

Tags: football, uefa, champions-league, europa-league

How many times has the Champions League, Europa League, Cup Winners' Cup, or European Super Cup final been played in the stadium of one of the finalists?

What were the results of each match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the European Cup/Champions League, this has happened four times:

- In 1957, Real Madrid played Fiorentina at their home stadium, the Santiago Bernabéu. Real Madrid won 2-0.
- In 1965, Inter Milan played Benfica at their home stadium, the San Siro. Inter Milan won 1-0.
- In 1984, Roma played Liverpool at their home stadium, the Stadio Olimpico. Liverpool won on penalties after a 1-1 draw.
- In 2012, Bayern Munich played Chelsea at their home stadium, the Allianz Arena. Chelsea won on penalties after a 1-1 draw.

In the UEFA Cup/Europa League, from 1972 until 1997, the final was held over two legs, with each finalist hosting one match. Since 1998, the final has been a single match held at a neutral venue, like the European Cup/Champions League. In that time, this has happened twice:

- In 2002, Feyenoord played Borussia Dortmund at their home stadium, De Kuip. Feyenoord won 3-2.
- In 2005, Sporting CP played CSKA Moscow at their home stadium, the Estádio José Alvalade. CSKA Moscow won 3-1.

Except for the inaugural Cup Winners' Cup, which used the same two-legged final format as the UEFA Cup, this occurred only once in that competition:

- In 1982, Barcelona played Standard Liege at their home stadium, the Camp Nou. Barcelona won 2-1.

From 1973 until 1997, the UEFA Super Cup final was also held over two legs, with each finalist holding one match. Between 1998 and 2012, the final was held at the Stade Louis II in Monaco; since then, it has been held at a different neutral venue each year. No team has played a UEFA Super Cup at their home ground since the switch to a single-match format.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted.